# How can i solve light reversed problem in ray tracing?

Tags: raytracing, shading

I'm making an image using python. But the Lambertian shading does not work.

At first the image saved like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3riB.png)

But when I reversed the normal vector of sphere, the image saved like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4uZo.png)

This is my shading code.

```
v = -m*ray

if s == 'Sphere':
    n = view.viewPoint - list[idx].c - v
    n =  -n / np.sqrt(np.sum(n*n))

for i in light:
    l_i = v + i.position - view.viewPoint
    l_i = l_i / np.sqrt(np.sum(l_i * l_i))

 x = list[idx].s.d[0] * i.intensity[0] * max(np.dot(l_i, n), 0)
 y = list[idx].s.d[1] * i.intensity[1] * max(np.dot(l_i, n), 0)
 z = list[idx].s.d[2] * i.intensity[2] * max(np.dot(l_i, n), 0)
```

list is sphere's list and idx is the number of the closest sphere.
I'd be grateful if anyone could help me. I have been doing this for a week

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated what you think is wrong.
Where is the light in relation to the spheres in the first image? Is it above and slightly behind them? If so - the image looks correct.
Assuming the statements above are correct, then the second image looks correct. The reason the light is on the bottom of the spheres is because the normal is now pointing "in" so the dot() product sign will be opposite to that in the first image.
Note that in your example code, it doesn't look like you have any shadow ray treatment. In other words - all objects will be lit as if all other objects are transparent. No objects will cast shadows on to other objects. This also explains why you can see the bottom of the spheres when the light is coming from the top. If you had proper shadow rays, then it wouldn't actually matter which way the normal is pointing (I would remove the max() functions at that point).

Comment: I found that my sphere intersect function has a mistake. So the m value is wrong. Thanks for the answer!!